# Rake at wrong version despite fresh uninstall/install procedures

Tags: ruby, rake, version, redmine

I am trying to install RedMine on a server.

During the procedures [as explained here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall) i am supposed to run

```
rake generate_secret_token
```

However, i am getting this error:

```
(in /home/var/redmine)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Rake::DSL
/home/var/redmine/Rakefile:7
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

After some research i discovered that rake 0.8.7 is supposedly having problems with this (that, at least, is how i understood it) and that i am supposed to use rake 0.9.2.2

I tried adding

```
gem 'rake', '0.9.2.2'
```

to my Gemfile.

I checked

```
rake --version
```

And get

```
rake, version 0.8.7
```

I ran

```
gem uninstall rake
```

Which succeeded, according to the output.

Then i ran

```
gem install rake -v=0.9.2.2
```

And the output was

```
Successfully installed rake-0.9.2.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rake-0.9.2.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for rake-0.9.2.2...
```

However, when then calling

```
rake --version
```

I still get

```
rake, version 0.8.7
```

I also experimented with adding

```
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
```

to my Gemfile for redmine. However, then i get this response when running rake

```
You have requested:
rake = 0.8.7

The bundle currently has rake locked at 0.9.2.2.
Try running `bundle update rake`
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: FYI: when you run `bundle install` it creates a Gemfile.lock so you don't accidentally change version numbers. If you change a version number in your Gemfile, you will have to run `bundle update` in order to update your lockfile with the new version numbers. It's also best if you are specific about which gems you want to update: `bundle update rake`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this strange issue by following these steps:

```
gem uninstall rake
```

Then

```
bundle update rake
```

This gave me the response that rake is already up-to-date, but still, i list it here - just in case.

Then

```
gem install rake -v=0.8.7
```

Furthermore in my Gemfile i had this configuration

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.6'
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
```

(In that order)

After doing all this i was able to run

```
rake generate_secret_token
```

successfully.

Answer (score 1):

When using several versions of a same gem, you can specify which version to use using `_version_` argument, eg. `rake _0.9.2.2_ --version`
(see `gem help install`)

To use Gemfile's version, you can prefix your command with `bundle exec`, eg. `bundle exec rake --version` (read "Getting started" from http://gembundler.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Basically the different incompatible versions of rake are creating problem. This solved it for me:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rake generate_secret_token
```